# Arch Linux: Wi-Fi Not Automatically Starting On Boot

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have recently installed Arch Linux on my laptop. I have setup the Wi-Fi without problem using `wpa_supplicant`, however it does not automatically start this on boot, and every time my system boots up, I have to manually run the following commands to reconnect:

```
sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp2s0
sudo dhclient wlp2s0
```

It gets pretty frustrating having to do this on every boot, so I am asking is there a way to **automatically run these commands on boot**?

I am using Plasma as the desktop environment, and a regular user account with sudo access (not the root user).

To be clear, the `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` file is set up perfectly fine, I just need to be able to automatically activate it on bootup, using the commands above.

Comment: What about your `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#At_boot_(systemd))? For Autostarting in general see [Autostarting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting). I like to throw all lines into [~/.xprofile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile)

Comment: @Devon Thanks I have read through this

Comment: @Philippos it says enp0s3, but I don't have Ethernet available (and no port on my laptop), my main interface which is not shown here is wlp2s0

Comment: Given that you don't use some other network management tool, why don't you put an `iface allow-hotplug` section in your `interfaces` config to auto-up the interface?